# C# images (.jpg) from PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, jpeg

I want to convert in C# a PDF file to .jpg's files. It should be one .pdf page in one .jpg file.
Can anyone explain me how to do it?

Best regards,
M.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to convert PDF to images.

To use **Ghostscript** from **.NET** you can take a look at the [**Ghostscript.NET**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) library (managed wrapper around the Ghostscript library).

Code sample of how to rasterize PDF to image can be found here: [**GhostscriptRasterizer sample**](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/RasterizerSample.cs)

Comment: The sample is now at https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/RasterizerSample1.cs

Answer (score 0):

*(Disclaimer I worked on this component at Software Siglo XXI)*

If you don't want to mess with Ghostscript API and need a quick working solution you could use **Super Pdf2Image Converter** to generate the images from a PDF in high resolution. It's available for both 32 and 64 bit and is very cheap and effective. I'd recommend you to try it.

You can take a look here: http://softwaresigloxxi.com/SuperPdf2ImageConverter.html

EDIT: Sample code...

```
// Instantiate the component
Pdf2ImageConverter p2i = new Pdf2ImageConverter(pdfPath);

// Get page count of a PDF file
int pages = p2i.GetPageCount();

// Get size of any page
int width, height;
p2i.GetPageSize(1, out width, out height);

// Convert any page of PDF to image file (preserving aspect ratio)
p2i.GetImage(outputImagePath, pageNumber, resolution, imageFormat);

// Convert any page of PDF to image (returns bitmap object)
Bitmap bm = p2i.GetImage(pageNumber, resolution, width, height, imageFormat);
```